# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://sample.ent

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var url= 'http://sample.net:8051/admin/singleprofile';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            crossOrigin: true,
            type: 'GET',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            accept: 'application/json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);                
        }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            var title, message;
            switch (xhr.status) {
                case 403:
                    title = xhr.responseJSON.errorSummary;
                    console.log('Please login to your server before running the test.');
                    break;
                default:
                    title = 'Invalid URL or Cross-Origin Request Blocked';
                    console.log('You must explicitly add this site (' + window.location.origin + ') to the list of allowed websites in your server.');
                    break;
            }
        });
```

From above code I am getting below issue:
You must explicitly add this site `(' + window.location.origin + ')` to the list of allowed websites in your server.

Comment: You need to do exactly what the error says: Add your origin to the allowed CORS list so that the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sample.net` is sent from the server.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers follow CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) policy. if you are sending request from local server to some external server in your case ("http://sample.net:8051/"), Browsers wont allow you to access resource. This issue you will face if you are requesting data to diff server, or even if you have same IP but running on different port. 
For more details check these links: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing 
 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

but this restriction wont be there once you deploy everything to one server in live environment. 
**for development purpose:**  
**for front end:** 
you can install CORS plugin for chrome. this plugin can enable/disable the CORS restriction in the browser

**For backend :** 
backend server can send the '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header in response with its value as *. so it will accept request for resource from any origin.